# How to add bluetooth icon on gnome-shell panel 3.10? (13.10 Gnome Ubuntu)

Tags: gnome, 13.10, bluetooth

How can I add an option (like 3.8 menu for example) on panel to turn on/off/settings bluetooh conection on Gnome 3.10?